# How exactly are realizability and the Curry-Howard correspondence related?

Tags: lo.logic, soft-question, computability-theory, type-theory, realizability

Consider, on the one hand:

- the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) between, on the one hand, types and terms (programs) in various flavors of typed $\lambda$-calculus, and on the other, propositions and proofs in various (generally intuitionistic) logical systems,

and on the other hand

- [realizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realizability), which is a relation between programs and propositions in various (generally intuitionistic) logical systems (the simplest form of which, Kleene realizability, is defined for example in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/323964/17064)).

Clearly the two have much in common; in fact, the rules describing the logical connectors in both are almost identical (e.g., a realizer of $\varphi\Rightarrow\psi$ is a program taking a realizer of $\varphi$ and returning a realizer of $\psi$, whereas the type corresponding to $\varphi\Rightarrow\psi$ under the C-H correspondence is the type of functions taking the type associated to $\varphi$ as input and returning the type associated to $\psi$ as output).

Now much of this similarity is simply due to the fact that both are ways to make precise the (informal) [Brouwer-Heyting-Kolmogorov interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer%E2%80%93Heyting%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_interpretation) of intuitionistic logic.  So maybe the similarity is just due to the connectors themselves.

Certainly there are important differences.  “Programs” in the C-H correspondence are written in a *strongly normalizable*, so, not Turing-complete, language, so *by construction* they cannot loop (indeed, “looping” would permit [paradoxical proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%27s_paradox) since any type is inhabited as soon as we have something like the $Y$ combinator), whereas “programs” in realizability are arbitrary Turing machines which *just so happen* not to loop in the cases we call them on [see also addendum below].  Also, the C-H correspondence appears to be a mostly formal observation about interpreting Cartesian closed categories with certain adjoints, whereas realizability seems to have deeper mathematical content.

It's also terribly hard to know exactly what to compare, because both the C-H correspondence and realizability have a gadzillion flavors, variants and reformulations, and I don't know where to start looking.

Still, I can't escape the feeling that there's more to be said than “they look similar because they both follow the B-H-K interpretation of connectives”.  For example, it seems to me that by reformulating Kleene realizability with terms of the untyped $\lambda$-calculus (with natural numbers as atoms) and then taking a model of the latter where each term is modelled as the set of terms of that type (“K-models” or something, I'm not sure what the right terminology is), realizability is brought even closer to the C-H correspondence.

So, **question**: do the Curry-Howard correspondence and realizability have more to do with each other than simply following the B-H-K correspondence?  Do they admit, for example, a common generalization?  Or a common framework in which we could define both?  (Side question: is the above above a fair summary of the situation?)

Please treat this as a soft question: I know various flavors of the Curry-Howard correspondence and of realizability, and I'm trying to “connect the dots” (and feel less confused about the relation between the two): any remarks that might help me do that is welcome.

---

**Addendum** (2023-12-06): I just remembered something worth mentioning in relation to this question as it is an important difference between realizability and Curry-Howard: there are propositional formulas that are uniformly realizable but not intuitionistically provable: so there is a program that realizes them (for all values of the propositional variables), but there is no program in the simply typed $\lambda$-calculus having the type that corresponds to the formula under the Curry-Howard isomorphism.  An example of such a formula (due to G. S. Tseitin [= Г. С. Цейтин]) is the formula
$$\begin{aligned}
&\big(\neg (A \land B) \land (\neg A \Rightarrow (C \lor D)) \land (\neg B \Rightarrow (C \lor D))\big)\\
\mathrel{\Rightarrow} &\big((\neg A \Rightarrow C)\lor(\neg B \Rightarrow C)\lor(\neg A \Rightarrow D)\lor(\neg B \Rightarrow D)\big)
\end{aligned}$$
[discussed here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/300362/17064) (for more examples, see [V. Plisko, “A Survey of Propositional Realizability Logic”, Bull. Symbolic Logiv, 15 (2009), 1–42](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25470303), esp. around §6).  The answer by Arno to the aforementioned MO question explains quite well what is going on here: Markov's principle (i.e., running two programs in parallel under the promise that one of them will halt), suitably used, gives us a way to realize a disjunction as the right-hand side of the implication above, but this kind of trick will not work to provide a term of the corresponding type.  So maybe this suggests a negative to my question: “realizability differs essentially from the Curry-Howard isomorphism in that realizability lets you use techniques such as Markov's principle to prove that programs terminate, which typiing does not permit.”

Comment: Decidedly not an answer, but on Monday, 18 December 2023 at 16:00 (UTC+1) Sundholm is set to give a [NOL seminar talk](https://scandinavianlogic.org/2023-12-02-NOL-Seminar-G%C3%B6ran-Sundholm.html) on a closely related question, titled ""Curry-Howard—a meaning explanation or just another realizability interpretation?""

Answer (score 11):

I am sure more than one exact correspondence can be made, but here's at least one that is technically precise. We shall employ categorical logic.

> *Executive summary:* realizability is the interpretation of intuitionistic logic in which predicates are interpreted using the subobject fibration, whereas the Curry-Howard interpretation uses the families fibration. The two fibrations are related by an adjunction.
> $\newcommand{\AA}{\mathbb{A}}$
> $\newcommand{\Asm}[1]{\mathsf{Asm}(#1)}$

Let me spell out the details a bit. I will follow the setup of [these notes](https://github.com/andrejbauer/notes-on-realizability) so that background material and further details are readily available.
Fix a partial combinatory algebra (pca) $\AA$, such as the pca of Turing machines or the untyped $\lambda$-calculus. Let $\Asm{\AA}$ the category of assemblies over $\AA$. Recall that an assembly $X = (|X|, E_X)$ is given by a carrier set $|X|$ and a map $E_X : |X| \to P(\AA)$ which assigns to each $x \in |X|$ a non-empty set $E_X(x)$ of its *realizers*.

We construe assemblies as types, and wish to set up an interpretation of logic on top of them. The first question is: *what are the predicates?* Two answers may be given:

1. The predicates on $X$ are the subojects of $X$ (chapter 4 of the notes). Up to equivalence, such a subobject is a map $\phi : |X| \mapsto P(\AA)$ which assigns sets of realizers to the elements of the carrier set $|X|$. The predicates on $X$ form a Heyting algebra $\mathsf{Sub}(X)$, and $\mathsf{Sub}$ itself is a fibration over $\Asm{\AA}$.
2. The predicates on $X$ are the families of assemblies indexed by $X$ (chapter 5 of the notes). Specifically, a predicate on $X$ is a map $F : |X| \to \mathsf{Obj}(\Asm{\AA})$ which assigns assemblies to the elements of the carrier set $|X|$. The families on $X$ form a category $\mathsf{Fam}(X)$ and $\mathsf{Fam}$ itself is a fibration over $\Asm{\AA}$.

The first interpretation is the realizability interpretation, and the second one is the Curry-Howard interpretation. Let us relate them.

Given an assembly $X$, there is a map
$$\mathbf{E} : \mathsf{Sub}(X) \to \mathsf{Fam}(X)$$
which assigns to a predicate $\phi : |X| \to P(\AA)$ the family defined by $\mathbf{E} \phi \,x  = (\lbrace{\star\rbrace}, (\star \mapsto \phi(x)))$. In words, we convert a subobject $\phi$ to a family of sub-terminal assemblies on $X$. We might call $\mathbf{E} \phi$ the *extent* of $\phi$.

In the opposite direction we have a map
$$\mathbf{T} : \mathsf{Fam}(X) \to \mathsf{Sub}(X)$$
which assigns to a family $F$ the subobject $\mathbf{T} F \, x = \bigcup_{y \in |F(x)|} E_{F(x)}(y)$. That is, $\mathbf{T} F \, x$ throws away the information about the assembly $F(x)$ and just keeps the realizers. We call $\mathbf{T}$ the *propositional truncation*.

It is obvious that $\phi = \mathbf{T} (\mathbf{E} \phi)$, while in the other direction we have a family map $\eta_X : F \to \mathbf{E} (\mathbf{T} F)$ which is the unit of an adjunction $\mathbf{T} \dashv \mathbf{E}$.

The composition $\mathbf{E} \circ \mathbf{T}$ appears as a type-theoretic construction known as *propositional truncation*. It allows us to express the relationship between Curry-Howard and logic internally in type theory, see for instance the HoTT book.

Comment: This is the sort of answer I was expecting, thanks. However, while I am convinced that (1) is indeed what I call “realizability”, I am confused about why (2) is indeed the Curry-Howard correspondence. But maybe that's because I have a too narrow view of the latter: for me, C-H connects proofs and programs, and I don't really see where the proofs appear in your description, and if the programs are elements of the pca, the problem I see is that I thought C-H applied to well-typed programs that must necessarily terminate, which elements of the pca may not be. Am I confused?

Comment: Or, to put my confusion in different terms: considering a propositional formula that is realizable but not provable in IPC (such as Tseitin's formula cited in the addendum to my question), how does it appear in the setup you describe? Is it that I'm trying to match apples and oranges?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a more proof-theoretic relationship between intuitionistic logic and intuitionistic type theory. Those would also be available, and are of a different kind (much more "logical").

Comment: As for the example given in your addendum, I would explain that one by noting that what is and is not realizable depend on the underlying pca. The formula in question is realized if we use Kleene's first pca (natural numbers encoding Turing machines), but is not realized if we use the simply typed $\lambda$-calclus (which forms a *typed* pca). It comes down to the obsercation that we may interleave the excution of several Turing machines, but we cannot interleave the terms of the $\lambda$-calculus.

Comment: Ah, so what you're saying is that if I ask about the relation between ⓐKleene realizability and ⓑthe C-H correspondence between some typed λ-calculus and some proof system, then my question is misguided because I'm changing several things at once (most notably the pca involved), is that right? That makes sense. But I remain confused as to why your item (2) “is” the C-H correspondence: can you clarify how I can relate the category $\mathsf{Fam}(X)$ you defined with a correspondence between propositions and types as in ⓑ, at least for some adequate $\mathbb{A}$? What corresponds to what?

Comment: I wonder if your question is even specific to realizability? The difference is just one of truncating existentials and disjunctions, see Definition 3.7.1 of the HoTT book. If you remove $\|{-}\|$ you get Curry-Howard. If you keep them, you get first-order intuitionistic logic. If you then interpret this in a realizability model you get what I was describing in my answer.

Comment: My question *was* about connecting what I knew as realizability with what I knew as Curry-Howard. Your answer made me realize that I was probably trying to connect apples and bananas, so that's nice. Now on the realizability side I think I understand what's going on in your point (1). What I still don't understand is the relation between your point (2) and what I know about C-H. So now it's no longer really about realizability, but I wish you could give some explanation as to how your setup (2) applies when connecting terms and proofs (or at least relates to it). What are $X$ and $\mathbb{A}$?

Comment: My (2) can be understood as the Curry-Howard interpretation of logic into type theory (predicates are types), composed with the interpretation of type theory into a realizability logi (dependent types are families of assemblies).